# Url Matching using Gruber's regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, gruber

how do I get the regex mentioned [in this article](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) working with preg_match in php?

```
<?php
preg_match("\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))/i", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Using the code above I get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash...
```

Comment: Note that this regex will allow URLs like `http://./` and `http://??/`. If this is not a problem to you, you should really use `filter_var('http://www.google.com/', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` instead, since it’s a built-in PHP function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#i", $text, $matches);
```

You were missing the regex delimiters (usually `/`, but using `#` here because it's more convenient for URLs)