# I can't get this regex to work properly

Tags: regex, url, preg-match, expression, match

I am desperatley trying to get John Grubers URL recognising regexs to work properly!  The simple function I wrote always returns false, even with a blatant URL in it!

I am trying to test for any url and web specific urls in 2 different functions.  I am fairly new to Regexs, so this is almost certainly me!

function:

```
<?php
function isweburl($url)
{
return(preg_match("(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:       [^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!    ()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))", $url));

}

function isanyurl($url)
{
echo "suspected url:$url<br>";
return(preg_match("/(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:    [^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!    ()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/", $url));

}

$test=isanyurl('http://www.sega.com');
var_dump($test);
echo "<br>web test:<br>";
$test=isweburl('http://www.sega.com');
var_dump($test);
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490310/regular-expression-for-checking-website-url - This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: An [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025095/url-matching-using-grubers-regex-in-php)

Comment: The original expressions, I am trying to get working, are at: [link](http://http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: Ah shoot, sorry Elias, you are absolutely right! Did look, but didn't find the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your regex.
I think preg_match needs a regex delimeter  "/ regex /" or "~ regex ~".
But, if you use the delimeter as a character in the regex body, it has to be escaped.

```
"     
 (?i)\b
 (
      (?:
           https?://
        |  www\d{0,3}[.]
        |  [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/
      )
      (?:
           [^\s()<>]+
        |  \(
           (
                [^\s()<>]+
             |  
                (
                     \([^\s()<>]+\)
                )
           )*
           \)
      )+
      (?:
           \(
           (
                [^\s()<>]+
             |  
                (
                     \([^\s()<>]+\)
                )
           )*
           \)
        |  [^\s`!    ()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]
      )
 )
"
```

Since your using `/` as a character, try using a different delimeter.
Expanded -

```
"~
 (?i)\b
 (
      (?:
           https?://
        |  www\d{0,3}[.]
        |  [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/
      )
      (?:
           [^\s()<>]+
        |  \(
           (
                [^\s()<>]+
             |  
                (
                     \([^\s()<>]+\)
                )
           )*
           \)
      )+
      (?:
           \(
           (
                [^\s()<>]+
             |  
                (
                     \([^\s()<>]+\)
                )
           )*
           \)
        |  [^\s`!    ()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]
      )
 )
~x"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I still can't get my head around Regexs, but thanks for helping me out :)